# Swapping divs in html code via javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, css

Let's say I have:

```html
<body>
<div id="1">test1 </div>
<div id="2">test2 </div>
<div id="3">test3 </div>
<div id="4">test4 </div>
</body>
```

What I want to do is take div with id "2" (or whichever I choose) and insert it at the end, right before closing .
How would I need to approach it? I basically want to swap already existing divs in html code itself via javascript.

Comment: What did you have tried so far?

Comment: For starter's `$('#2').appendTo('body')`, rest after you share the code

Comment: When do you want to swap it?

Answer (score 1):

This will work

```js
$('body').append($('#2'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div id="1">test1 </div>
<div id="2">test2 </div>
<div id="3">test3 </div>
<div id="4">test4 </div>
</body>
```

Comment: `remove` is redundant.

Comment: @KarenBarseghyan  Hope this is what you were looking for. Please do not forget to upvote and accepting the answer. Although we love to help,we also love those reputation point. Code on!

Answer (score 0):

You question is ambiguous. Swapping is switching places of two things. What you described is just moving a div at the end of the list. Result: "1 3 4 2". Swapping would mean that you will get "1 4 3 2".

If you want just to move something at the end with the web api you can just write

```
<script>
    let el = document.getElementById("1");
    let parent  = el.parentElement;
    parent.appendChild(el);
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you, works without Jquery which is what I needed.